# How to convert packed DMS (with decimal point) to decimal degrees

Tags: coordinates, data-conversion

I have the following coordinates in a dataset :

352215.78N  0041448.71E
352351.58N  0041637.08E
324554.53N  0883049.65W
324016.54N  0883153.19W
374733.00S  1450640.30E
374606.50S  1445054.20E

I believe that those coordinates are in packed DMS with decimal point).

Unfortunately, I don't know a lot about this unit, and I couldn't find a documentation I understood.

Is there a particular way to convert packed DMS with decimal point to DMS (ultimately I will convert it in decimal degrees) ? Is it just a 1/10000 to apply ?
Should I pay attention to E(+),W(-), N(+), S(-) ?
If anyone has a clear and understandable documentation to propose on the subject, i'll take it !

I'm sure it's something easy, but it's just not quite clear to me...

Answer (score 0):

The Packed DMS format is just the coordinates in Decimal, Minutes and Seconds omitting the units. That means your coordinates can be easily translated from `352215.78N` to `35º 22' 15.78"`.

The translation to decimal degrees can be done dividing by 60 as for any conversion for sexagesimal to decimal:

```
35º 22' 15.78" = 35º (22 + 15.78/60)' = 35º 22.263' = (35 + 22.263/60)º = 35.37105º (decimal degrees).
```

A more practical calculation would be: `35 + 22/60 + 15.78/3600`.

The longitude coordinates have an additional position before tehe decimal point as it could reach up to `180º`, but the mechanism is the same, just remove the `0`:

```
0041448.71 = 4º 14' 48.71" = ...
```

Finally, just as you comment, in decimal degrees west (W) and south (S) coordinates are considered negative, so you must add a minus symbol:

```
0883153.19 W = 88.5314417 º W = -88.5314417º
```